# How can i decode this json?

Tags: php, json

Hi i have an issue with decoding json that looks like this
code:

```
$tmp=($this->request->post['info']);
    echo $tmp;
```

result:

```
{"views":{},"vectors":"{\"front\":{},\"back\":{}}","teams":"{}","fonts":"","product_id":"217","parent_id":"0","design_id":null,"design_file":"blabla","designer_id":123,"design_key":0,"product_color":"Sapphire","user_id":"0","design_name":"asd","weight":0,"is_private":0}
```

if i decode this result is null

im tryung to do this but no results

```
    $tmp=json_encode($this->request->post['info']);
    echo $tmp;
    $tmp=str_replace('\'{','{',$tmp);//' dont even ask
    $tmp=str_replace('}\'','}',$tmp);
    $tmp=str_replace('"{','{',$tmp);//' dont even ask
    $tmp=str_replace('}"','}',$tmp);
    $tmp=stripslashes($tmp);
    echo $tmp;
    $tmp=json_decode($tmp,true);

    $data = $tmp;
```

result stays the same... i just want to decode this:`{"views":{},"vectors":"{\"front\":{},\"back\":{}}","teams":"{}","fonts":"","product_id":"217","parent_id":"0","design_id":null,"design_file":"blabla","designer_id":123,"design_key":0,"product_color":"Sapphire","user_id":"0","design_name":"asd","weight":0,"is_private":0}`

no need to decode `vectors` as array, i mean it's ok if it stays string
maybe the break near the `"teams"` is reason?

Comment: you mean `json_decode($json);`? What happens if you are using this function?

Comment: You are using json_encode instead of json_decode. Try $tmp=($this->request->post['info']); var_dump(json_decode($tmp));

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
<?php
$json = '{"views":{},"vectors":"{\"front\":{},\"back\":{}}","teams":"{}","fonts":"","product_id":"217","parent_id":"0","design_id":null,"design_file":"blabla","designer_id":123,"design_key":0,"product_color":"Sapphire","user_id":"0","design_name":"asd","weight":0,"is_private":0}';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($decoded);
```

Yielded for me:

```
Array
(
    [views] => Array
        (
        )

    [vectors] => {"front":{},"back":{}}
    [teams] => {}
    [fonts] => 
    [product_id] => 217
    [parent_id] => 0
    [design_id] => 
    [design_file] => blabla
    [designer_id] => 123
    [design_key] => 0
    [product_color] => Sapphire
    [user_id] => 0
    [design_name] => asd
    [weight] => 0
    [is_private] => 0
)
```

Which looks completely valid. I think that your line:

```
$tmp=json_encode($this->request->post['info']);
```

makes no sense because it looks like you have json-formatted string, and you encoding this again.

What you get from frontend is string, and you have to decode it to get array (in my case) or a class.

Answer (score -1):

`$jsonEncodedString = json_encode($tmp);
echo $jsonEncodedString;`

You don't have to strip any slashes. On the contrary. You have to express the echo-ed text as PHP source code.

The backslash () is a special character in both PHP and JSON. Both languages use it to escape special characters in strings and in order to represent a backslash correctly in strings you have to prepend another backslash to it, both in PHP and JSON.

There are two special characters that needs escaping in single quote strings: the apostrophe (') and the backslash (). While the apostrophe always needs escaping, the PHP interpreter is forgiving and allows unescaped backslashes as long as they do not create confusion. However, the correct representation of the backslash inside single quoted strings is \.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: You've got this completely wrong, you decode json-encoded strings, not encode them again

Comment: @jedruniu @wylliam-delaunay i found the reason, i've used `htmlspecialchars_decode` function to solve it, i think it happend coz i use FormData for AJAX sending pictures, and 'info' data with it

Comment: allright I see, sorry about my mistakes, I'm just trying to help @jedruniu